# Mocha - Experimental support for decorators is a feature that is subject to change in a future release

Tags: typescript, mocha.js, ts-node

I'm trying to run a unit test with `Mocha` using the below command in `Windows`.

```sh
mocha --require ts-node/register test.spec.ts
```

and getting the following error

```
error TS1219: Experimental support for decorators is a feature that is subject to change in a future release. Set the 'experimentalDecorators' option to remove this warning.
```

This is despite having the following in my `tsconfig.json` file.

```
"experimentalDecorators": true,
```

Can anyone advise how I reference the `tsconfig.json` file?

Comment: I have tried the command in different directories, including the one with the tsconfig but still get the same error.

Comment: I have also tried `mocha --require ts-node/register --compilerOptions '{"experimentalDecorators": true}' test.spec.ts` but get the same error.

Comment: If I run this directly from the directory that has my `tsconfig.json` then I get a different error `Unexpected token import`.

Comment: I can get the test to run if I remove `"module": "es6",` from my tsconfig. However this breaks then my whole site.

Answer (score 0):

In my `package.json` script, I set the path of my `tsconfig.json` file in the environment variable `TS_NODE_PROJECT` using `cross-env`:

By running something like this, you should be able to solve the decorator problem:

```
cross-env TS_NODE_PROJECT=<your-ts-config-json-file> mocha --require ts-node/register test.spec.ts
```